# LinearLayoutManager setReverseLayout() == true but items stack from bottom

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, reverse, layout-manager

This seems like it would be an easy solution, but it seems that setting

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

.... // More code

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    // Add item decoration
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(DIVIDER_SPACE));

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true); // THIS ALSO SETS setStackFromBottom to true
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Seems to also set the items to stack from the bottom

I tried to set `setStackFromBottom` to false but that didn't do anything, what would be the best way to reverse the items order but still populate from the top? Should I use a Custom Comparator class instead? I was hoping this would be an easier process than creating another class.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

from the docs for [setReverseLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean))

> Used to reverse item traversal and layout order. This behaves similar to the layout change for RTL views. When set to true, first item is laid out at the end of the UI, second item is laid out before it etc. For horizontal layouts, it depends on the layout direction. When set to true, If RecyclerView is LTR, than it will layout from RTL, if RecyclerView} is RTL, it will layout from LTR. If you are looking for the exact same behavior of `setStackFromBottom(boolean)`, use `setStackFromEnd(boolean)`

So, try also using [setStackFromEnd(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean)) on your LinearLayoutManager instance,

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Comment: Good job, that WAS easy :)

Comment: Thanks, tried both methods separately, didn't even have a thought about using them together to get the result :)

Comment: I'm getting `can not resolve method setReverseLayout` error.

Comment: @ReazMurshed  check your sdk version (min and target) and dependencies (recycler view support lib) used in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My problem was a silly one. I was using `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` instead of `LinearLayoutManager`.

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't scroll to end to show newest items

Comment: @Elliptica why would it?  When calling `stackfromEnd(true)`, the list fills its content starting from the bottom of the view. If you would like to move the list position to the end of the list, there are ways to do that and has been questioned and answered in other posts.

Comment: @petey @ReazMurshed if both `setStackFromEnd()` and `setReverseLayout()` are doing the same job then why use both of them? Is there any other reason to call both of these methods together?

Comment: after setting setStackFromEnd  = true, setReverseLayout behavior stop working.
Please help.

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer works well and I went through a hardship to make it work as I was getting `can not resolve method setReverseLayout` error.

Then after searching for solutions I found there was a silly mistake out there. I was using `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` instead of `LinearLayoutManager`.

So I thought to remove the confusions around here I need to put it as an answer.

**Do not use `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` instead of `LinearLayoutManager`**

```
// Declare your RecyclerView and the LinearLayoutManager like this 
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
```

...

```
// Now set the properties of the LinearLayoutManager 
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

// And now set it to the RecyclerView
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Comment: is there any drawback in using LinearLayoutManager instead of RecyclerView.LayoutManager?

Comment: A `LinearLayoutManager` is a `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`. You don't use `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` directly unless you're making your own implementation of it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the effective method to solve this using xml:

```
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
app:stackFromEnd="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a RecyclerView with **horizontal** orientation and for some unknown reason(s) the accepted answer didn't work for me when i tried to reverse the layout with `setReverseLayout(true)`.

but doing it via XML worked fine.

```
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:reverseLayout="true"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, i work put in false

```
recyclerView = vista.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

For search in my app, search for name

```
Query busqueda = databaseReference.child("Productos").orderByChild("pTitle").startAt(txtSearch.getText().toString());
            busqueda.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    postModelList.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        PostModel postModel = ds.getValue(PostModel.class);
                        postModelList.add(postModel);
                        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postModelList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```