# Android reverse recylcerview

Tags: android

i add basically some properties to `recyclerview` to set reverse such as this code:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/messagesView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
       app:reverseLayout="true"
       app:stackFromEnd="true"/>
```

what i try to do? i'm trying to show last item in recyclerview without scroll to last position, in pasted code i have first item in start and i have to scroll to last position programmatically

how can i change this xml layout to have this ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted any Java code. So try this:

Set this LayoutManager to the RecyclerView.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, VERTICAL, true));
```

Comment: LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL. That means it's a vertical list.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the attributes from code? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727354/linearlayoutmanager-setreverselayout-true-but-items-stack-from-bottom), that seems to work.

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Comment: i remove properties from xml code and i try to set that programical, but it doesn't change view and i have list normally

Answer (score 1):

Its worked for me , Moves the **focus on Last item of the RecyclerView.**

```
 mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView,null, finalCustomItems.size()-1);
```

or,

```
mPagerAdapter.highlightPosition(listView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
```