# How to animate recyclerview contents change when switch item ordering between Ascending and Descending

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My current Android application displays a list of personal details.
The users can order the list by full name either ascending or descending.

The ordering toggle works fine, however the user experience is not acceptable.

I am using adapter updateList with DiffUtil and the change is confusing

I've tried also "scrolling to top" when the update is complete howver this doesnt really improve the user experience.

Is there a Best Practice for handling complete reversing a lists contents?

Comment: If you are using `recyclerview`, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727354/linearlayoutmanager-setreverselayout-true-but-items-stack-from-bottom

Comment: @HeisenBrg I am using recyclerView, but cannot see how the link you posted will help me